# p4merge displays error 'nul is (or points to) an invalid file' when I am using git difftool --cached

Tags: git, p4merge

I just decided and installed p4merge as my visual merge tool for git. In order to do that I've configured my git using this command

```
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd 'p4merge $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED'
```

And then I tested them and ran `git difftool` command and it worked just fine. but when I ran `git difftool --cached`, p4merge displayed an error message:

```
nul is (or points to) an invalid file
```

I also tried to follow the instructions in this [blog](http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/05/12/installing-and-using-p4merge-in-git-for-windows/), but I couldn't resolve the problem.

By the way I use git & p4merge on windows 7.  Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Please use backticks for formatting commands, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for more information.

Comment: did you fill the `[diff]` and `[difftool "p4merge"]` sections?

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue. Works until i try with --cached or --staged parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say based on the given information, but I had the same issue due to whitespaces in the file under comparison. I use Linux instead, and I fixed it thanks to this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108635/why-i-cant-escape-spaces-on-a-bash-script):

Just search for: `bar "$@"`